# Why ">" is ok to be in value of XML file, but "<" is not?

Tags: xml, validation

Here is an example of XML file:

```
<tag value=">this is well formatted xml"/>
```

This can be loaded successfully in MSXML and Apache Xerces.

```
<tag value="<this is not"/>
```

This will failed.

I think the Greater Than sign and Less Than sign are both illegal in the XML file, when they are not being used as tag seperator. But the above example shows the Greater Than sign is ok.

Can anybody explain or give a link to a document about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask "why" one is illegal and the other not. The answers to "why" questions about XML syntax are often rooted in its SGML history - the designers of XML wanted to ensure that it was a strict subset of SGML and could be parsed by SGML parsers. SGML allowed freedom in areas where XML does not, for example omitting the quotes around attribute values, and this accounts for some of the restrictions that XML has inherited.

Comment: Hi Mike, I am still interested in original supporting documents. Any RFC or link in w3c.org would have satisfied me :)

Comment: I interpreted your question as meaning that you knew it was illegal, and you wanted to know why it was designed that way. For the actual rule, see section 2.4 rule [14] of the XML 1.0 Recommendation in the case of character data, or rule [10] for attributes.

Comment: Thank you. I found it as you suggested:
The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section.

Comment: Mike, I thought Greater Than sign is also illegal, but the real life example I found shows it is not. So I want to look at the original definition to make sure I know which one is illegal and which one is not. Thanks you to point me to the exact section of the document.

Answer (score 3):

**Only the characters "<" and "&" are strictly illegal in XML.** The greater than character is legal, but it is a good habit to replace it.

```
 Entity References

    Some characters have a special meaning in XML.

    If you place a character like "<" inside an XML element, it will generate an error because the parser interprets it as the start of a new element.

    This will generate an XML error:
    <message>if salary < 1000 then</message>

    To avoid this error, replace the "<" character with an entity reference:
    <message>if salary &lt; 1000 then</message>

    There are 5 predefined entity references in XML:
    &lt;    <   less than
    &gt;    >   greater than
    &amp;   &   ampersand 
    &apos;  '   apostrophe
    &quot;  "   quotation mark

    Note: Only the characters "<" and "&" are strictly illegal in XML. The greater than character is legal, but it is a good habit to replace it.
```

EDIT 1:

source link http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

you can get more information related to XMl

**Example:**

Here is what the variable looks like improperly coded in an XML file:

```
<mail id="a1" to="&<manager>@mycompany.com" …
```

Here is what the variable looks like properly coded in an XML file:

```
<mail id="a1" to="&amp;&lt;manager&gt;@mycompany.com" …>
```

Comment: Could you please give source of the text? It looks good, but I would like to see if it is from accredited source. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the link to w3schools.com. It is a good place to new learners, but I would like to see some original documents such as RFC or w3c document...